# How to write a complex .bashrc shortcut

Tags: git

I started using .bashrc to write shortcuts to git commands I use often.

I struggled a lot with this because 99% of all the tutorials out there do not work for me for some bizarre reason. For example using a profile file and other suggestions do nothing.

.bashrc does work though so I started writing these:

```
alias gg='git gui'
alias gs='git status'
alias gb='git branch'
alias gc='git checkout'
```

etc

The next I want to add is this something a bit more complex, something that constructs a command like this:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/X X
```

Because git always asks me to input that silly command in all the time and it's time consuming.

I started looking at functions and I tried something like this:

```
alias gsu='function _gsu(){ "git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/$1 $1"}'
```

So I can type

```
gsu foo
```

and it will try to run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/foo foo
```

But it doesn't work.

Any idea how to complete this command to make it functional?

Comment: You've got an alias which defines a function? Why not just include the function as a function?

Comment: I use [bash-it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it), which is a helpful bash framework for such similar tasks, that provides alias, theme, plugins. Checkout their [git alias](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/blob/master/aliases/available/git.aliases.bash)

Answer (score 1):

Dont alias the function.

Just rename the function from `_gsu` to `gsu`

After reloading your config file, you should be able to do `gsu foo`, which will run `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/foo foo`

Comment: @Nick - What does it do instead of working? Be more specific.

Comment: It's hard to explain the terminal behaviour. You get those > characters under the command as if it had turned into a text editor

Answer (score 1):

Two pieces of advice for you.

First, for your `gsu` function, simply define the function in your .bashrc, without trying to make an alias of it.

```
gsu() {
    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/"$1" "$1"
}
```

But for your collection of shell aliases, my approach would be to replace ALL of these with a single one:

```
alias g=git
```

And then put your shortcuts into your `~/.gitconfig` file. Here's part of what I use:

```
[alias]
  st   = status -sb
  co   = checkout
  ci   = commit
  br   = branch
  lg   = log --decorate --graph --all  --format='%C(yellow)%h%Creset %Cred%d%Creset %s %Cgreen%an%Creset (%C(cyan)%ar%Creset)'
```

Then, if you want to create a branch named "foo", you type:

```
$ g br foo
```

It's not quite as tight as your two-character shell aliases, but it keeps all your git-related configuration in your git config file, which I like.

Comment: Sorry didn't work. Would be nice if you could include an example on how you would  call the gsu function.

Comment: Also the way you declare the function is wrong. It should be function gsu {}
Have you actually tried this first?

Comment: Hi Nick.  No, the way I defined the function is just fine, and is POSIX-compliant. Adding the word `function` in front is a bash extension that is functionally equivalent to the POSIX notation. If something didn't work for you, it would be useful to say HOW it didn't work, since my crystal ball is on the fritz today. As to how to use the function .. I would imagine it would function the way you intended your alias to function. How do YOU want it to work? And can you confirm that you are in fact using bash? You didn't tag it in your question.

Comment: If you do it your way the terminal enters in a state of limbo where it skips a line and then waits until you type something. Not sure how to explain it. Why does it work with you and not with me?

Comment: Heh, no, if YOU do it my way you get odd results. Works for me.  :)  It sounds like something is waiting for input, but I can't diagnose the problem from this distance, but perhaps you have leftover functions or aliases from previous attempts. Try running `type gsu` and `type git` in your shell to make sure you're running what you expect to run.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by doing this.

First declare a function like this:

```
function gsu {
   git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/$1 $1
}
```

and then define it like this:

```
alias gsu='gsu'
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. Didn't know that. Still not sure why I need to declare functions differently from you to get them to do anything